# Is it possible to generate an information box like infoBox () by basicPage (), instead of by dashboardPage, in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

Is it possible to generate an information box like infoBox () by basicPage (), instead of by dashboardPage, in shiny? My script is already done with basicPage, and I didn't want to change its structure, just add a few boxes with numerical information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import the `shinydashboard` CSS files in your app and use `infoBox`:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- basicPage(
  tags$head(
    includeCSS(
      system.file("shinydashboard.css", package = "shinydashboard")
    ),
    includeCSS(
      system.file("AdminLTE", "AdminLTE.css", package = "shinydashboard")
    )
  ),
  
  infoBox(
    "Approval Rating", "60%", icon = icon("line-chart"), color = "green",
    fill = TRUE
  )
  
)

server <- function(input, output){}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```